# How to pass a value of a type and convert it to another type?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm trying to pass an integer value from an activity to another one.
In the second activity I want to convert my string to an integer to do some calculations and convert it again to a string for showing it in a TextView.

This is my first activity:

```
public class GetPrice extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.getprice);
    final EditText et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.getprice);
    Button getb1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.getbutton);

    getb1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent i1 = new Intent(GetPrice.this, Price1.class);
            int fl1 = Integer.parseInt(et1.getText().toString());
            i1.putExtra("theprice", fl1);
             startActivity(i1);
        }
    });
```

And this is my second activity:

```
public class Price1 extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.price1);


    String st1 = new String(getIntent().getExtras().getString("theprice"));

    Integer int1 = Integer.valueOf(st1);

    //some calculation with int1

    TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.price1text);
    tv1.setText(String.valueOf(int1));

}
```

But, when I press the "getbutton", the application crashes.

what is the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the error stack trace?

Comment: sorry, I don't have a virtual device and only i can run it on my device.

Comment: Perform debug on your real device and post the stack trace, please.

Comment: how is that?... sorry, i'm very new in android.

Comment: Get the basic info from this link - http://eclipsetutorial.sourceforge.net/debugger.html

Comment: Enable debug mode in device and see logs using adb (from eclipse or Intelij)

Comment: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/debugging-with-logcat.html

Comment: First proper answer belong to @Tobor! Undelete your post please :)

Comment: @Mariusz: No, because he downvoted... Thank you for your loyalty!

Comment: @MariuszS: and... your answer is more complete than mine, so mine became useless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Bundle.getInt(String key)` for accessing `int fl1` putted in `GetPrice` class.

```
 Integer int1 = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("theprice");
```

Updated to older JDK.

Also you dont need to reconvert values from type to type like this:

```
String st1 = new String(getString...);
Integer int1 = Integer.valueOf(st1);
tv1.setText(String.valueOf(int1));
```

The should be simplified to code like this

```
String st1 = Integer.toString(getString...);
tv1.setText(st1);
```

or even better

```
Integer int1 = getInt...;
tv1.setText(String.valueOf(int1));
```

Comment: i give this error if use "getint" : "The constructor String(int) is undefined"

Answer (score 3):

Without the stacktrace and the actual error, either

```
int fl1 = Integer.parseInt(et1.getText().toString());
```

is the problem, and the `String` isn't a textual representation of an integer, or that's actually working and this:

```
String st1 = new String(getIntent().getExtras().getString("theprice"));
```

is the problem because you stored an `Integer` in extras and are now trying to get it as a `String` (use `getInt("theprice")` instead).

Comment: i give this error if use "getint" : "The constructor String(int) is undefined"

Comment: then i give this error: "String.valueof cannot be resolved to a type"

Comment: `Integer.toString(getIntent().getExtras().getInt("theprice"))`

Comment: Honestly, if you don't understand the very, very basics of the language/programming (types) you are going to have many more issues. Starting with a beginners book on programming/java or the tutorials provided by oracle is highly recommended.

Comment: you are right Brian, what is your recommend book or tutorial?